# Running protractor tests on IE

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, protractor

I was using vm xp on MAC. MAC and vm are in a network but I'm unable to run protractor tests.
When I run, after pointing Selenium address to vm PC IP in n config file, I can see the IE browser initiating and see the nodejs app URL but I'm unable to access the app.

The nodejs server is running on port 9001 and the app is running on 9009 on my local computer which is a Mac PC.

I can browse the app manually with the IP address 10.0.2.2 on vm but not with protractor config.

I am missing something. Don't I need to open ports on the Mac?
What baseurl in protractor config should I use?
I have pointed selenium address to vm ip address and it is working.

And also the nodejs server is running at 0.0.0.0:9001 port.

Answer (score 0):

The testing story for VM's is a little rough, but there are a few approaches to this:

1. adding a common hostname (`myapp.local`) to `/etc/hosts` (and the windows host file) and using that as the protractor `baseUrl`
2. Separating the IE tests from other tests and using the host machine's ip as your baseUrl: baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:9000/'

Alternately, you can use a service like [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com) or [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com) and run your tests on IE through "the cloud". If you can afford the cost i'd highly recommend them.